# Problema SMPSEQ3 - Fun with Sequences - SPOJ

Tags: array, c++

Bom dia.
Gostaria de uma ajuda para criar um código que seja aceito pelo SPOJ.

O problema proposto é o seguinte:
"Você recebe uma sequência ordenada de n inteiros S = s1, s2, ..., sn e uma sequência ordenada de inteiros m Q = q1, q2, ..., qm. Por favor, imprima na ordem crescente todos esses que não pertençam a Q."

Estou tentando fazê-lo em C++ e usando vetores. Mas estou esbarrando num loop infinito que não estou sabendo tratar.

E ainda não pensei em como fazer a comparação entre os vetores e exibir os que estão presentes apenas na sequencia S.

Segue o código que fiz até agora:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int S, Q;
    cin >> S;
    int * S_vetor = new int[S];

    for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        cin >> S_vetor[i];
    }
    cin >> Q;
    int * Q_vetor = new int[Q];

    for (int i = 0; i <= Q; i++) {
        cin >> Q_vetor[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Desde já, fico grato pela atenção.

Comment: quais os valores que tu estás entrando para S e Q, quando o programa roda?

Comment: Sugiro colocar mensagens de texto antes dos `cin` - acho que esse é o teu "loop infinito"...

Comment: Os valores entre -100 e 100.
Como assim, mensagens de texto antes dos cin?

Comment: Ah, no CodeBlocks ele tá com a endentação...

Comment: o `cin` bloqueia a execução. Se não digitaste todos os valores esperados, parece que o programa travou... Coloca uns `cout >> "digite o valor de..."`, por exemplo...

Comment: Mas o SPOJ exige que a resposta seja apenas para aparecer igual o exemplo deles: Apareça o tamanho do vetor, embaixo seus elementos.
Em seguida o tamanho do outro vetor, embaixo seus elementos.
Por ultimo, apenas os inteiros que estão no primeiro vetor e não no segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Demorei para perceber, mas encontrei o "loop infinito"

Nesse for:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Q; i++)
```

Tu estás esperando por um elemento a mais do que o lido, por causa do teste `i <= Q`. Lembre-se que teu for começa em zero, por isso para ler Q elementos, tu precisas testar `i < Q`.

A impressão de loop infinito dá-se porque há um `cin` esperando por um input que nunca ocorre.